# How to send messages between a web client and a JADE multi-agent system?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I am working on a JADE project and I want to build a React app to interact with my agents.

I would like to send messages to specific agents from my web client using REST. I know that it is possible to send POST requests, but what the body should look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create an agent programmatically you can sent message to the agent by means of `AgentController.putO2AObject`, but you need server code that processes your rest message and delegate it to the agent.

Otherwise you can just create `java.net.ServerSocket` in agent code and sent any message you want from your client

Comment: Ok I see, I thought that since agents use post requests to communicate and I know their adresses I can intercat with them directly from the client.
So it's not possible... Thank you!

Comment: you can also try to use add-ons (https://jade.tilab.com/download/add-ons/), I think WSIG or WSDC are appropriate in your case

Answer (score 0):

take a look at these https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer2.html and https://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html.

You may one to create the agents using pure java and invoke it from the UI using React via REST or MVC.

Comment: How exactly can I use REST? I did not find it in the docs. How do I form my POST requests ?